# jquery div replacement independently

Tags: jquery

I have 3(or more but here 3) blue DIV displayed and there are 3 more same size red DIV wich are hidden.

What I want to do: when a blue div is clicked this blue div is hidden and replaced by the appropriate red div(each red div content is going to be different) and other blue div stay blue if these ones have not been clicked.

and then as we click on the red div it hides and display the original blue div back.

My html/css

```
    <style type="text/css">

        body{width: 900px;}

        #first, #second, #third{background: blue;float: left; margin-right: 100px; width: 200px;height: 200px;color: white;}

        #first-toggle, #second-toggle, #third-toggle {background: red;float: left; margin-right: 100px; width: 200px;height: 200px;color: white;display: none;}


    </style>
```

```
<div id="first">I'm an image</div>

<div id="second">I'm an image</div>

<div id="third">I'm an image</div>


<div id="first-toggle">I'm an content</div>

<div id="second-toggle">I'm a content</div>

<div id="third-toggle">I'm an content</div>
```

I thank you in advance for your future answers or even if you take the time to read it at least ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of jquery's hide() and show(). working example here

http://jsfiddle.net/jpezK/4/

Comment: Sometimes when one of the div is clicked, another becomes red too don't know why

Comment: that's because the divs are not in order.. use firebug to see the position

Comment: Y ok in fact div are sliding :/ otherwise that's great

Comment: everything is alright, I applied it to the real images and content thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this great solution using the most simple html markup. 

Copy-paste divs at wish!

[**D E M O  1**](http://jsbin.com/ocuje6/7)

or:

[**D E M O  2**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/gnm2d/1/)

...and here are my 'just for fun' playarounds

[**D E M O  3**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/gnm2d/)

[**D E M O 4**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/gnm2d/2/) with a hover stuff :D

Comment: You really like programming ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use replaceWith in your case.

Check out this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpezK/) and you'll understand.

More information on replaceWith [here](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: Only does half the solution you cant get from red to blue.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a Q&A for getting your code done for free. It's a Q&A for getting help achieving what you want. When OP takes a look at my answer, he will easily be able to fix the rest of the code himself.

Comment: Yes the probleme is that in fact the first div will be an image and the second a content div but thanks

Comment: @rsplak I added the fix to the rest and it seemed to end up deleting the divs after a few clicks (using chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/s6T75/

Comment: Y it does that's the effect i wanted thank you I 'll check to fix the deleting div problem 

I'm a js jquery beginner sry

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jpezK/5/ I did it and it seems the same problem appears after few clicks it disappears

Comment: @ rsplak i'm sorry I've tried many things with toggle etc and it seems it was not the appropriate way so I didn't know how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link the solution.. http://jsfiddle.net/ZyBkA/3/

hope this is what you require !

Comment: Yes it's exactly that just I have to make it switch back but i'm going to try thank you

Comment: when I click the red div after it appears the blue div should come back

Comment: no on my chrome :/ and as the first is clicked the last becomes red

Comment: it's working fine, I just changed the content inside, so you can know that when I click an image, it's the corresponding toggle that is coming in, and regarding your chrome, just try on other browsers, it should work just fine ! or restart your chrome/PC ..